# Jsrender with space

Tags: javascript, jsrender

Hi this code not working becouse of the space between, Peter __ Mark, how can i acchieve this with space?
The code is, x-jsrender

```
    <div class="node">

 {{if title == 'Peter Mark'}}
 <div><a href= {{>id}} >{{>title}}</a><br />{{>subtitle}}</div>
 {{else title == 'VD'}}
  <div><a href= {{>id}} >{{>title}}</a><br />{{>subtitle}}</div> 
  {{else}}
   <div><a href='#'>{{>title}}</a><br />{{>subtitle}}</div>
  {{/if}}
```

Comment: Can you remove this question, since it is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177591/possible-issue-in-jsrender-with-spaces. Also can you 'accept' my reply on the other one, so people don't get confused. Need to make it clear it is simply an error in your code not a JsRender issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is an error in the template.
`<a href= {{>id}} >` should be `<a href='{{>id}}'>`.

As to `{{if title == 'Teamledare Redovisning'}}` that will work fine. Not an issue with JsRender at all.

BTW I would usually write the above as `{{if title==='Teamledare Redovisning'}}`. The extra white space you have makes it harder to parse - though it will work fine. Similarly I would write `{{else title==='VD'}}`.