# Possible issue in JSRender with spaces

Tags: javascript, jsrender

i have some problem with rending this jsrender code, it works if title == 'Teamledare Redo' but if i have more words like this: 'teamledare Redovisning', then it not works..

Why does it not render when there is more words ?

```
  <script id="oc_template" type="text/x-jsrender">

   <div class="node">

 {{if title == 'Teamledare Redovisning'}}
 <div><a href= {{>id}} >{{>title}}</a><br />{{>subtitle}}</div>
 {{else title == 'VD'}}
  <div><a href= {{>id}} >{{>title}}</a><br />{{>subtitle}}</div> 
  {{else}}
   <div><a href='#'>{{>title}}</a><br />{{>subtitle}}</div>
  {{/if}}

    </div>
```

Comment: i dont get any error, it just dont render

Comment: you mean like this?:    <div><a href= "{{>id}} >{{>title}}"</a><br />{{>subtitle}}</div>

Comment: change `{{else title == 'VD'}}` to `{{else if title == 'VD'}}`

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, Its working already, Except if i have a title that is longer then 7-8 characters its not works

Comment: @Pilot No {{else if title == 'VD'}} is incorrect.

Comment: @Rasmus - you may have a problem with <a href= {{>id}} > - you probably want <a href='{{>id}}'>. {{if title == 'Teamledare Redovisning'}} Should work. If not - can you create a jsfiddle to show it not working...

Comment: @BorisMoore that is 10000% correct..

Comment: @Rasmus - I answered both this and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169207/jsrender-with-space. Also it would be good to remove one or both of them since they dups:  and change the title above to reduce confusion. (I did already propose a modified title, which may go through anyway)... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK - buried in the comments above is the following:

The problem is that there is an error in the template.
`<a href= {{>id}} >` should be `<a href='{{>id}}'>`.

As to `{{if title == 'Teamledare Redovisning'}}` that will work fine. Not an issue with JsRender at all.

BTW I would usually write the above as `{{if title==='Teamledare Redovisning'}}`. The extra white space you have makes it harder to parse - though it will work fine. Similarly I would write `{{else title==='VD'}}`.